# IBM RTC-- Hiding work items in backlog that have been pulled into sprints

Tags: rtc, backlog

I have been a little flustered recently at a feature I don't really understand in the IBM RTC web client (and thick client), version 5.0.2. Any work items that I have currently planned for the current sprint still show up in the backlog. This makes grooming/planning very difficult. I was wondering if anyone has found a way to automatically hide these items? Or, for that matter, hide them at all? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe with an expression filter? https://jazz.net/forum/questions/109428/exclude-work-item-types-or-show-only-certain-work-item-types-in-plan-view